# How to apply a self-made function to every element of a list, returning a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have written a function called `mutpath_fun(x,y)` that returns a data frame consisting of every possible mutational pathway between a given pair of amino acids `(x,y)`. This is an example output of the function for `"A"` and `"W"`":

```
   STA_AA S_NUC INT_AA1 INT_NUC_1 INT_AA2 INT_NUC_2 END_AA E_NUC
1       A   GCU       S       UCU       C       UGU      W   UGG
2       A   GCU       S       UCU       S       UCG      W   UGG
3       A   GCU       A       GCG       S       UCG      W   UGG
4       A   GCU       A       GCG       G       GGG      W   UGG
5       A   GCU       G       GGU       G       GGG      W   UGG
6       A   GCU       G       GGU       C       UGU      W   UGG
7       A   GCC       S       UCC       C       UGC      W   UGG
8       A   GCC       S       UCC       S       UCG      W   UGG
9       A   GCC       A       GCG       S       UCG      W   UGG
10      A   GCC       A       GCG       G       GGG      W   UGG
11      A   GCC       G       GGC       G       GGG      W   UGG
12      A   GCC       G       GGC       C       UGC      W   UGG
13      A   GCA       S       UCA       *       UGA      W   UGG
14      A   GCA       S       UCA       S       UCG      W   UGG
15      A   GCA       A       GCG       S       UCG      W   UGG
16      A   GCA       A       GCG       G       GGG      W   UGG
17      A   GCA       G       GGA       G       GGG      W   UGG
18      A   GCA       G       GGA       *       UGA      W   UGG
19      A   GCG       S       UCG    <NA>      <NA>      W   UGG
20      A   GCG       G       GGG    <NA>      <NA>      W   UGG
```

Now, I am trying to call this function for every possible amino acid combination and combine the results of all of these into a larger data frame by rowbinding. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

This is what I have been trying:

1. using a `foreach()` loop

```
aa_poss <- 
  c("A","R","N","D","B","C","E","Q","Z","G","H","I" ,"L","K","M","F",
    "P","S","T","W","Y","V","*")

aa_routes <- tibble(expand.grid(aa_poss, aa_poss))
saaset <- as.character.factor(aa_routes[[1]])
eaaset <- as.character.factor(aa_routes[[2]])
allaamutpaths <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(aa_routes), .combine = 'rbind') %dopar% {
  mutpath_fun(saaset[i], eaaset[i])
}
```

The program stalls when I run this and does not complete. This could be because my `mutpath_fun()` involves 2 nested `foreach()` loops already.

2. `map2_dfr()` from `purrr`

```
aa_poss <- 
  c("A","R","N","D","B","C","E","Q","Z","G","H","I" ,"L","K","M","F",
    "P","S","T","W","Y","V","*")

aa_routes <- tibble(expand.grid(aa_poss, aa_poss))
saaset <- as.character.factor(aa_routes[[1]])
eaaset <- as.character.factor(aa_routes[[2]])
map2_dfr(saaset, eaaset, mutpath_fun)
```

I get the following error message: `Error in { :  task 1 failed - "task 1 failed - "task 3 failed - "attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>"""`

Here is more information:
desired input:

```
a_poss <-  c("A","R","N","D","B","C","E","Q","Z","G","H","I" ,"L","K","M","F",
    "P","S","T","W","Y","V","*")

aa_routes <- tibble(expand.grid(aa_poss, aa_poss))
```

this is the `mutpath_fun`, which requires the `tidyverse`, `combinat`, `foreach`, `doParallel`, `micropan` packages:

```
registerDoParallel()

aa_poss <- c("A","R","N","D","B","C","E","Q","Z","G","H","I" ,"L","K","M","F",
    "P","S","T","W","Y","V","*") #defining possible amino acids 

aa_nuc <- function(aa) {
  if (aa == "A") {
    return (nucs = c("GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "R") {
    return (nucs = c("CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGA", "AGG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "N") {
    return (nucs = c("AAU", "AAC"))  
  }
  if (aa == "D") {
    return (nucs = c("GAU", "GAC"))  
  }
  if (aa == "B") {
    return (nucs = c("AAU", "AAC", "GAU", "GAC"))  
  }
  if (aa == "C") {
    return (nucs = c("UGU", "UGC"))  
  }
  if (aa == "E") {
    return (nucs = c("GAA", "GAG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "Q") {
    return (nucs = c("CAA", "CAG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "Z") {
    return (nucs = c("CAA", "CAG", "GAA", "GAG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "G") {
    return (nucs = c("GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "H") {
    return (nucs = c("CAU", "CAC"))  
  }
  if (aa == "I") {
    return (nucs = c("AUU", "AUC", "AUA"))   
  }
  if (aa == "L") {
    return (nucs = c("CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUA", "UUG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "K") {
    return (nucs = c("AAA", "AAG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "M") {
    return (nucs = c("AUG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "F") {
    return (nucs = c("UUU", "UUC"))   
  }
  if (aa == "P") {
    return (nucs = c("CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"))   
  }
  if (aa == "S") {
    return (nucs = c("UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "AGU", "AGC"))   
  }
  if (aa == "T") {
    return (nucs = c("ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"))  
  }
  if (aa == "W") {
    return (nucs = c("UGG"))   
  }
  if (aa == "Y") {
    return (nucs = c("UAU", "UAC"))   
  }
  if (aa == "V") {
    return (nucs = c("GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"))    
  }
  if (aa == "*") {
    return (nucs = c("UAA", "UGA", "UAG"))  
  }
} #amino acid to nucleotide function

mutpath_fun <- function(S_AA, E_AA) {
  start <- as.character(aa_nuc(S_AA))
  end <- as.character(aa_nuc(E_AA))
  allroutes <- expand.grid(start,end) #finding all possible amino acid routes between nucleotides
mut_path <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(allroutes), .combine = 'rbind') %dopar% {
  S_NUC <- as.character(allroutes[[1]][i]) #extract starting nucleotide
  split_S_NUC <- S_NUC %>% strsplit("") %>% unlist()   #split starting nucleotide into character vector
  E_NUC <- as.character(allroutes[[2]][i])   #extract ending nucleotide
  split_E_NUC <- E_NUC %>% strsplit("") %>% unlist()   #split ending nucleotide into character vector
  poss_mut_pos <- which(split_S_NUC != split_E_NUC)   #compare possible mutation positions 
  template <- as.data.frame(cbind(S_NUC, E_NUC)) %>% mutate(INT_NUC_1 = NA, INT_NUC_2 = NA)   #create template & prepare for mutation loop
  template <- template[ ,c(1,3,4,2)] #reorder columns
  if (length(poss_mut_pos) != 1) {
    perm_list <- tibble(combinat::permn(poss_mut_pos)) #generate all possible mutational pathways 
    template <- template %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(perm_list)))
    foreach(j = 1:sapply(perm_list, length)) %do% {
      pathway <- perm_list[[1]][j] %>% unlist()    #transform a mutational pathway into a numeric vector 
      foreach(k = 1:(length(pathway)-1)) %do% { 
        new_nucleotide <- split_E_NUC[pathway[k]] #split ending nucleotide for pasting
        split_pathway_nuc <- template[j,k] %>% str_split("") %>% unlist()   #split current nucleotide 
        split_pathway_nuc <- split_pathway_nuc %>% replace(pathway[k], new_nucleotide) #mutate 
        template[j,k+1] <- split_pathway_nuc %>% paste(collapse = "") %>% unlist()  #save updated nucleotide
      } 
    }
    template
  }
}
mut_path <- mut_path %>% mutate(INT_AA1 = translate(mut_path$INT_NUC_1, no.stop = FALSE), INT_AA2 = translate(mut_path$INT_NUC_2, no.stop = FALSE)) #get intermediate amino acids
mut_path <- mut_path %>% mutate_all(na_if,"") #add in NAs for cells with empty values
start_AA_col <- rep(S_AA, nrow(mut_path)) 
end_AA_col <- rep(E_AA, nrow(mut_path))
mut_path <- cbind(mut_path, end_AA_col, start_AA_col) 
mut_path <- mut_path %>% select(start_AA_col, S_NUC, INT_AA1, INT_NUC_1, INT_AA2, INT_NUC_2, end_AA_col, E_NUC) 
mut_path <- mut_path %>% rename(STA_AA = start_AA_col, END_AA = end_AA_col)
return(mut_path)
}
```

desired output (this is the first 2 rows of the data frame, after omitting where `x == y`):

```
structure(list(STA_AA = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), S_NUC = c("CGU", 
"CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", 
"AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", 
"CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", 
"AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", 
"CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", 
"AGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGC", "CGC", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", 
"AGG", "AGG", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAC", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", 
"AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC"), INT_AA1 = c("G", "P", 
"G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", 
"S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", 
"S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "R", 
"R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", "G", 
"R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "T", "G", "G", "R", "R", "T", "T", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", 
"R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "T", "T", "G", 
"T", "D", "T", "D", "D", "N", "N", "T", "T", "D", "D", "N", "N", 
"T", "T", "D", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", 
"K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", 
"T", "T"), INT_NUC_1 = c("GGU", "CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGU", "CGU", 
"CCC", "CCC", "GGA", "GGA", "CGU", "CGU", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CCG", "CCG", "GGA", "GGA", "AGU", "AGU", 
"ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "GGG", "AGU", "AGU", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", 
"GGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CCU", "CCU", "GGC", "CCC", "GGA", "GGA", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", "GGG", "CGC", "CGC", "CCG", 
"CCG", "GGA", "GGA", "AGC", "AGC", "ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "GGG", 
"AGC", "AGC", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", "GGU", "CGA", "CGA", "CCU", 
"CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CCC", "CCC", "GGA", "CCA", 
"GGG", "GGG", "CGA", "CGA", "CCG", "CCG", "GGA", "ACA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "AGA", "AGA", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", "GGU", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CCU", "CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGG", "CGG", "CCC", "CCC", "GGA", 
"GGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", "CCG", "GGA", "GGA", 
"AGG", "AGG", "ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "ACG", "GAU", "ACU", "GAC", 
"GAC", "AAU", "AAU", "ACC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", "AAC", "AAC", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GAC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", "AAA", "AAA", "ACU", 
"ACU", "GAC", "GAC", "AAA", "AAA", "ACC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", 
"AAG", "AAG", "ACU", "ACU", "GAC", "GAC", "AAG", "AAG", "ACC", 
"ACC"), INT_AA2 = c(NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", 
"G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", 
"P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", 
"T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", 
"P", "A", NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", 
"G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", 
"G", "G", "T", "T", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "D", "D", "T", 
"T", "A", "A", "D", "D", "T", "T", "A", NA, NA, "A", "E", "E", 
"T", "T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", "T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", 
"T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", "T", "A"), INT_NUC_2 = c(NA, NA, 
"GCC", "GGU", "GGU", "CCU", "CCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GGU", "GGU", 
"CCU", "CCU", "GCA", "GCG", "GGU", "GGU", "CCU", "CCU", "GCG", 
"GCA", "GGU", "GGU", "ACU", "ACU", "GCA", "GCG", "GGU", "GGU", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GCG", "GCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCU", 
NA, NA, "GCA", "GGC", "GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GGC", 
"GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCG", "GCA", "GGC", "GGC", "ACC", "ACC", 
"GCA", "GCG", "GGC", "GGC", "ACC", "ACC", "GCG", "GCU", "GGA", 
"GGA", "CCA", "CCA", "GCU", "GCC", "GGA", "GGA", "CCA", "CCA", 
"GCC", NA, NA, "GCG", "GGA", "GGA", "CCA", "CCA", "GCG", NA, 
NA, "GCG", "GGA", "GGA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCG", "GCU", "GGG", "GGG", 
"CCG", "CCG", "GCU", "GCC", "GGG", "GGG", "CCG", "CCG", "GCC", 
"GCA", "GGG", "GGG", "CCG", "CCG", "GCA", NA, NA, "GCA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "ACG", "ACG", "GCA", NA, NA, NA, NA, "GCC", "GAU", "GAU", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GCC", "GCU", "GAC", "GAC", "ACC", "ACC", "GCU", 
NA, NA, "GCU", "GAA", "GAA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCU", "GCC", "GAA", 
"GAA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCC", "GCU", "GAG", "GAG", "ACG", "ACG", 
"GCU", "GCC", "GAG", "GAG", "ACG", "ACG", "GCC"), END_AA = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A"), E_NUC = c("GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG")), row.names = c(NA, -160L), class = "data.frame")
Browse[1]> outpute
Error during wrapup: object 'outpute' not found
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Browse[1]> view(output)
Browse[1]>  dput(rbind(mutpath_fun("R", "A"), mutpath_fun("N","A")))
structure(list(STA_AA = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), S_NUC = c("CGU", 
"CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", 
"AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", 
"CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", 
"AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", 
"CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", "AGG", 
"AGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGU", "CGC", "CGC", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", "CGA", 
"CGA", "CGG", "CGG", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", "AGA", 
"AGG", "AGG", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAC", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", 
"AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", "AAU", 
"AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC", "AAC"), INT_AA1 = c("G", "P", 
"G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", 
"S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", 
"S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "S", "S", "T", "T", "G", "G", "R", 
"R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", "G", 
"R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "T", "G", "G", "R", "R", "T", "T", "G", 
"G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "G", 
"R", "R", "P", "P", "G", "P", "G", "G", "R", "R", "T", "T", "G", 
"T", "D", "T", "D", "D", "N", "N", "T", "T", "D", "D", "N", "N", 
"T", "T", "D", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", 
"K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", "T", "T", "D", "D", "K", "K", 
"T", "T"), INT_NUC_1 = c("GGU", "CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGU", "CGU", 
"CCC", "CCC", "GGA", "GGA", "CGU", "CGU", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "CGU", "CGU", "CCG", "CCG", "GGA", "GGA", "AGU", "AGU", 
"ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "GGG", "AGU", "AGU", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", 
"GGU", "CGC", "CGC", "CCU", "CCU", "GGC", "CCC", "GGA", "GGA", 
"CGC", "CGC", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", "GGG", "CGC", "CGC", "CCG", 
"CCG", "GGA", "GGA", "AGC", "AGC", "ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "GGG", 
"AGC", "AGC", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", "GGU", "CGA", "CGA", "CCU", 
"CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGA", "CGA", "CCC", "CCC", "GGA", "CCA", 
"GGG", "GGG", "CGA", "CGA", "CCG", "CCG", "GGA", "ACA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "AGA", "AGA", "ACG", "ACG", "GGU", "GGU", "CGG", "CGG", 
"CCU", "CCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CGG", "CGG", "CCC", "CCC", "GGA", 
"GGA", "CGG", "CGG", "CCA", "CCA", "GGG", "CCG", "GGA", "GGA", 
"AGG", "AGG", "ACA", "ACA", "GGG", "ACG", "GAU", "ACU", "GAC", 
"GAC", "AAU", "AAU", "ACC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", "AAC", "AAC", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GAC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", "AAA", "AAA", "ACU", 
"ACU", "GAC", "GAC", "AAA", "AAA", "ACC", "ACC", "GAU", "GAU", 
"AAG", "AAG", "ACU", "ACU", "GAC", "GAC", "AAG", "AAG", "ACC", 
"ACC"), INT_AA2 = c(NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", 
"G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", 
"P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", 
"T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", 
"P", "A", NA, NA, "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", 
"G", "G", "T", "T", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", 
"G", "P", "P", "A", "A", "G", "G", "P", "P", "A", NA, NA, "A", 
"G", "G", "T", "T", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "D", "D", "T", 
"T", "A", "A", "D", "D", "T", "T", "A", NA, NA, "A", "E", "E", 
"T", "T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", "T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", 
"T", "A", "A", "E", "E", "T", "T", "A"), INT_NUC_2 = c(NA, NA, 
"GCC", "GGU", "GGU", "CCU", "CCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GGU", "GGU", 
"CCU", "CCU", "GCA", "GCG", "GGU", "GGU", "CCU", "CCU", "GCG", 
"GCA", "GGU", "GGU", "ACU", "ACU", "GCA", "GCG", "GGU", "GGU", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GCG", "GCU", "GGC", "GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCU", 
NA, NA, "GCA", "GGC", "GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GGC", 
"GGC", "CCC", "CCC", "GCG", "GCA", "GGC", "GGC", "ACC", "ACC", 
"GCA", "GCG", "GGC", "GGC", "ACC", "ACC", "GCG", "GCU", "GGA", 
"GGA", "CCA", "CCA", "GCU", "GCC", "GGA", "GGA", "CCA", "CCA", 
"GCC", NA, NA, "GCG", "GGA", "GGA", "CCA", "CCA", "GCG", NA, 
NA, "GCG", "GGA", "GGA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCG", "GCU", "GGG", "GGG", 
"CCG", "CCG", "GCU", "GCC", "GGG", "GGG", "CCG", "CCG", "GCC", 
"GCA", "GGG", "GGG", "CCG", "CCG", "GCA", NA, NA, "GCA", "GGG", 
"GGG", "ACG", "ACG", "GCA", NA, NA, NA, NA, "GCC", "GAU", "GAU", 
"ACU", "ACU", "GCC", "GCU", "GAC", "GAC", "ACC", "ACC", "GCU", 
NA, NA, "GCU", "GAA", "GAA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCU", "GCC", "GAA", 
"GAA", "ACA", "ACA", "GCC", "GCU", "GAG", "GAG", "ACG", "ACG", 
"GCU", "GCC", "GAG", "GAG", "ACG", "ACG", "GCC"), END_AA = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A"), E_NUC = c("GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCU", "GCU", 
"GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCU", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", 
"GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCC", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", 
"GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCA", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", "GCG", 
"GCG", "GCG")), row.names = c(NA, -160L), class = "data.frame")
```

Let me know if there is anything else you need!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Sounds like it could be a problem with the code in `mutpath_fun`

Comment: also, are you sure you want to include calls to `mutpath_fun()` where `x` and `y` are the same? i.e. `aa_routes` is 529 rows long, but 23 of them have `Var1` equal to `Var2`

Comment: EDIT: @MrFlick I included the function and more clarification on what the input should be.  @langtang Good catch, I could add an `if()` which avoids these function calls

Comment: @MrFlick also included the beginning of the desired output

Comment: It is a lot of code to grasp for an outsider. It would help a lot if you'd boil down the question to a very short example, and apply it to your specific use case yourself.

Comment: I don't get that 'every possible mutation path between two amino acids' is so regular in form. I think the result must be a list of vectors as paths which are of different lengths.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).